# What does this command do ? "az .\-u"

Tags: azure, azure-cli

```
az .\-u
```

I accidentally run this command and the cli started some work then I pressed <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd> to terminate it but I'm afraid something has been already done. How to check if something changed?

I've checked the [cli reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/reference-index), but couldn't find a similar command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*As there is no such command in `Az`, even though I entered the same as you, I received an error as shown*:

[image]

*If you want to check your activities for any changes, there are couple of ways:*

1. ***Check the Log Activity***: *To check your log activity, use below PowerShell command: (default activity status exists for 90 days)*

```
Get-AzActivityLog -StartTime 2022-11-01T10:30 -EndTime 2022- 11-14T11:30
```

**Note:** *According to your requirements, you can obtain logs across resource group by applying start time, and end time parameters*.

[image]

2. *To check for any specific changes held in resources, use below query with "Azcli" command*

```
Search-AzGraph -Query 'resourcechanges | extend changeTime=todatetime(properties.changeAttributes.timestamp) | project changeTime, properties.changeType, properties.targetResourceId, properties.targetResourceType, properties.changes | order by changeTime desc'
```

***Received Output also includes a changetime attribute:***

[image]

3. Through Azure portal, Activity logs can also be checked using path:  `Monitor -> Activity Log`

[image]

Reference: [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/resource-graph/how-to/get-resource-changes?tabs=azure-powershell#run-your-resource-graph-query)